# How to Implement an Anti-XSS Warning Text to be Displayed in the Console upon Opening DevTools?

Tags: reactjs, xss, devtools

I'm looking for ways to add warning text about XSS (cross-site scripting) protection to the developer console when opening DevTools. How can I implement something like this? I would be grateful for any tips, code samples or recommendations on this topic. I use React.

[Discord Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7sqQ.png)
[Facebook Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ayjZ.png)

The only solution I could think of is to send this text to the console every 30 seconds, as I couldn't find a way to detect the opening of DevTools.